# MySQL query select rows from table according to specific key that is not in another table

Tags: mysql, select

How to select all exams by its ID and title (from table 'exams'), that a student (in table 'grades') hasn't written yet?

TABLE: grades

```
+--------------+----+----
|student_number|e_id| ...
+--------------+----+----
|888075        |1   | ...
|888075        |2   | ...
|888075        |4   | ...
|637020        |2   | ...
+--------------+----+----
```

TABLE: exams

```
+----+------+
|e_id|title |
+----+------+
|1   |exam 1|
|2   |exam 2|
|3   |exam 3|
|4   |exam 4|
+----+------+
```

In this particular case I would expect the following output for student `888075`:

```
+--+------+
|id|title |
+--+------+
|3 |exam 3|
+--+------+
```

I just need the inverse selection of this:

```
SELECT e.e_id as id, e.title as title
FROM grades g
LEFT JOIN exams e
ON g.e_id = e.e_id
WHERE g.student_number = '888075'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query was close -- just reverse the joins and check for `null` accordingly:

```
SELECT e.e_id as id, e.title as title
FROM exams e
   LEFT JOIN grades g ON g.e_id = e.e_id
      AND g.student_number = '888075'
WHERE g.e_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select those `e_id` that are not in `e_id`'s that student participated.

```
SELECT aa.e_id AS id, aa.title
FROM exams AS aa
WHERE e_id NOT IN (
    SELECT e_id
    FROM grades
    WHERE student_number = '888075'
    GROUP BY e_id
);
```

OR

```
SELECT aa.e_id AS id, aa.title
FROM exams AS aa
WHERE e_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT e_id
    FROM grades
    WHERE student_number = '888075'
);
```

OR

```
SELECT aa.e_id AS id, aa.title 
FROM exams AS aa 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT e_id 
    FROM grades AS bb
    WHERE aa.e_id = bb.e_id AND bb.student_number = '888075'
);
```

Comment: `Not In` is a perfectly good option, but I would guess using `distinct` or `group by` in the subquery would actually make it slower.  Without that it should be equivalent to the `outer join / null` check.  I actually generally prefer to use `Not Exists`, but unfortunately it doesn't perform as well in `mysql` -- http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Thank you that you explain optimizations and improvements! I have read something similar about Not Exists. After i read better the question I bet OP wanted exactly what you posted (+1).